# Cmake warning: runtime library may be hidden by files in: /usr/local/lib

Tags: linux, cmake, linker

I have recently installed some libraries in `/usr/local/lib`.
Since then, cmake (via gui) gives a warning when configuring

```
runtime library [libmpi.so.40] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in: /usr/local/lib
```

I have read many sources about this (see below), and I guess I understand the cause.
I also understand one should remove the warning.
I am not sure I have any preference for which of the locations `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` or `/usr/local/lib` are a better option, possibly any of the two is ok.
But to be on the safe side, I would rather use `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

Item #0 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69742501/2707864) suggests to make sure that CMake chooses the library which you are actually intended to use. That motivates line 1 below, even if from the answer it is not clear for me that line 1 is enough to "make sure that...".

Item #2 in the answer suggests removing the unwanted path from `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, if that is the cause for the "wrong" directory being searched by the loader. I guess I would need a tool to know which library is loaded, so I can add/remove the "wrong" directory from `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and see if that has any effect. I don't know how to ascertain that, nor it is explained in that answer. That motivates line 2 below, just in case it helps.

So I followed suggestions there as much as possible, without success.
Remove the new libraries is not an option for me.

If I understand correctly, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48452833/2707864) suggests there is no systematic way to tackle the issue, which surprises me.

What I tried:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib
$ ccmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu ..
```

and it didn't work.

How can I solve this?
I would much appreciate getting suggestions about *what to do*.
The general explanation of the cause is somewhat clear.

**Related**

1. [CMake cannot resolve runtime directory path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536567/cmake-cannot-resolve-runtime-directory-path)
2. [CMAKE - runtime library hidden files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447728/cmake-runtime-library-hidden-files)
3. [CMake+OpenCL+CUDA -> runtime library may be hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67484266/cmakeopenclcuda-runtime-library-may-be-hidden)

Comment: From [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69742501/3440745): "Make sure that CMake chooses the library which you are actually intended to use" - If this is the case, then setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` doesn't help in fixing the error. "If the "wrong" directory is searched by the loader because it is included into the variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH..." - As far as I know, the path `/usr/local/lib` is searched by the linker NOT because of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable. So setting this variable fixes nothing.

Comment: "Any hints?" - The are many hints in the questions and answers you reference. Do you want **more hints**? In that case add bounty to the existing question. In the current state your question is just re-iterating e.g. of [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536567/cmake-cannot-resolve-runtime-directory-path) (that is, a duplicate).

Comment: @Tsyvarev - 
1) "Make sure that..." How would I do that? You mention what *does not help*, but I didn't see what *does help* described, maybe I missed the point.
2) "If the wrong..." How would I avoid that? You mention what *is not the cause*, but I didn't see what *is the cause* described, and then *what to do* (or at least try), maybe I missed the point again.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - "Any hints?" was a mild way of stating the question, so I fixed the exact meaning, thanks for pointing that out. I think this is not a dupe, I saw no one reporting that he/she tried what I tried, without success. So the question is similar/related to others (quite usual in SE!), but it is not a dupe.
Actually I found your answers most instructive, but I think I tried all the specific actions you suggest.

Comment: "I think I tried all the specific actions you suggest." - Well, you haven't tried the way 1 from my answer: uninstalling the library from the wrong location. You have two instances of `libmpi.so.40` library, why don't remove one of them? Preferably the one `/usr/local/lib/libmpi.so.40`, as the other one comes with the package. You may even try to remove the file manually (but prepare its backup somewhere else).

Comment: @Tsyvarev - As mentioned in the OP, uninstalling is not an option for me. So I should have said "I think I tried all the specific actions you suggest (that I can afford to)." Is there any other alternative, for this case? Which ones? 
In addition, if you have any answers for the points 1 and 2 raised in my comment, that would be very helpful. 
I also commented on aspects of your answer that were not clear for me. Thanks for sharing your knowledge! –

Comment: You ask hints specific for your situation, but don't provide enough details about your situation. All we know is the error message and that you "have recently installed some libraries in `/usr/local/lib`". At the beginning of my answer there is a list of conditions for the warning. Provide such list for your **specific case**. Like "1. My project links with `libmpi.so.40` which exists both at `/usr/local/lib` and at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. 2. I want to link with the library at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. 3. But the loader searches under `/usr/local/lib` because <...>."

Comment: You could also try to manually set RPATH for you executable. Just set [BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH.html) property of the executable to TRUE, and set property [INSTALL_RPATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INSTALL_RPATH.html) to the desired list of RPATH. After building, run `ldd` for your executable and verify that it finds all libraries on proper places. (Proper places you may find from the linker's command line generated by CMake, that command line will be printed when build the project with `make VERBOSE=1`.)